# What does "setContentView" really do?

Tags: android

In my main activity, I would like to have it set up, so that I first get met by a `contentView` just showing a background and some text. After X seconds, I want to change to my other view (`GLSurfaceView`).

This is obviously something I am doing completely wrong.

This is how I've imagined it could've been done (it's all in the `onCreate` method):

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}

viewer = new Viewer(this);

setContentView(viewer);
```

Where layout `Main` is what I want to show at the beginning and `Viewer` is my `GLSurfaceView` class.

What happens is that it just goes black for 10 seconds and then it starts loading the objects I've got that is shown through OpenGLES.

There's nothing wrong with the layout `Main`, since it works if I just erase the lines under where the `Thread.sleep` takes action. Though, nothing happens before the `Thread.sleep` is over...

**With that said, my questions are following:**

- Why is the `contentView` not changing until **after** `Thread.sleep` is done?
- What would be an appropiate solution to what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming this in your onCreate() and thats why you are seeing nothing.

The way I would implement this is to start a thread using AsyncTask sleep in the doInBackground and in the onPostExecute set up the new view.

Answer (score 2):

Don't make sleep the main thread(UI thread).Use a `threads`,`AsynkTas`k or `TimerTask` for that type of works instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're not sleeping the UI thread in the way you think you are.

The simplest thing for what you're looking to achieve is to separate the views into separate activities and let Android handle the transition between the views. It adds another file to your codebase, but it's fairly straightforward. Let's say your initial, plain view (`R.layout.main`) is for a `SplashActivity` activity, and your post-splash view goes into `PostSplashActivity`. Then you could do something like this:

```java
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    private static long DELAY = 10000; //milliseconds;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    new Handler().postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent postSplash = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, PostSplashActivity.class);
                    SplashActivity.this.startActivity(postSplash);
                    SplashActivity.this.finish();
                }
            }, DELAY);
    }
}
```

This will draw your `R.layout.main` layout, and then puts a `startActivity` call for your `PostSplashActivity` on the message queue and tells the queue to wait `DELAY` milliseconds to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are making the main thread sleep. This may be why the code is running tell after.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like a splash screen. I like to think of these as separate to the following screen, so always use a separate activity rather than calling setContentView twice. You'd still need to sleep in a thread.

Just personal preference though...